# Как выбрать все дочерние категории главной категории?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Не получается выбрать все дочерние категории главной категории.
Структура таблицы category:
[image: структура таблицы category]

У каждой категории есть parent_id. Если parent_id = 0, это значит родитель
Нужно выбрать все category_id родителя в один массив.
Вот кусок кода, с которым я работал. Но он не выводит 3-4-5 вложенность категорий:
$filter_category_id тут родитель

```
if ($filter_category_id) {
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $cats = array($filter_category_id);
        $cats = $this->model_catalog_category->getChildCategories($filter_category_id, $cats);

        $cats_merge = array();
        if ($cats) {
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                $catsa = $this->model_catalog_category->getChildCategories($cat);
                $cats_merge = array_merge($cats_merge, $catsa);
            }
        }
        $cats_merge = array_merge($cats_merge, $cats);
        $cats_merge = array_unique($cats_merge);

        return $cats_merge;
    }
```

А тут обращение к таблице:

```
public function getChildCategories($id, $cats = array()){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id  = " . $id;
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $rows = $result->rows;
    if($rows){
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $cats[] = $row['category_id'];
            $this->getChildCategories($row['category_id'], $cats);
        }
    }
    return $cats;
}
```

Нашел решение:

```
     public function getCategoriesandSubs($parent_id = 0) {
  static $cat_branch = array();
  $results = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND c.status = 1");
  $num_rows = count($results->rows);
  if($num_rows != 0) {
     foreach ($results->rows as $result) {
        $cat_branch[] = $result['category_id'];
        $this->getCategoriesandSubs($result['category_id']);
     }
  }
  if(count($cat_branch) == 0) {
    $cat_branch[] = $parent_id;
  }
  return $cat_branch;
```

}

Comment: Сходу наверное ничего дельно и не предложишь, НО, недочет я вижу тут: `$this->getChildCategories($row['category_id'], $cats);`, у вас эта функция выполняется, но результат теряется ибо он никуда не сохраняется, возможно есть смысл сделать так? `return $this->getChildCategories($row['category_id'], $cats);` - Добавить return

Answer (score 0):

Естественно, этот запрос не выдаёт подкатегорий, поскольку в нём этого не прописано.  
Вот тут, похоже, ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697446/how-do-i-represent-a-tree-structure-in-a-mysql-table  
Не открывается. Ну, тогда вот: https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/ — эта открывается, там есть примеры, как раз MySQL+PHP.  
Хотя я б таки подумал над сменой БД и способа представления дерева, если это не критично.

Comment: `Хотя я б таки подумал над сменой БД` - на какую бд вы собрались менять?

Comment: Дык я-то ни на какую ;)  <br/>А вообще, в Postgres есть пользовательские типы данных. На них много чего интересного можно написать.

Comment: Как вариант представления дерева, для которого не нужен Postgres: представляем узлы битовыми строками. Строка представляет собой путь к узлу — 01 от узла к первому сыну, 10 от узла к младшему брату, 00 путь закончен. Тогда все потомки выбираются простым запросом по префиксу.  Да, забыл добавить, что Postgres умеет иерархические запросы именно к вашим таблицам.

Comment: Рекурсивные запросы доступны везде уже лет так 10, как и работа с битами.

Comment: В MySQL 8.0 не нашёл. В документации предлагают рекурсивную процедуру. В любом случае, другие способы просто таки обязаны быть быстрее и удобнее (личное мнение).

Comment: *В MySQL 8.0 не нашёл.* Искал поди именно рекурсивные запросы? а искать-то надо было [рекурсивные CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive). Там и [пример](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal) есть именно для иерархических данных.